# How does chromium detect my location with a VPN on?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, location, chromium, geoip

I have a VPN on and no program should have direct un-VPN'd net access.  On google maps I say "show my location" and it gets my exact location from the html5 geolocation API.  How is chromium able to know my location?

Comment: maybe you vpn send HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header or try clear your cache

Comment: Are you using it with turned on mobile connection? If yes, then check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try running chrome with --no-quic. QUIC is UDP protocol enabled by default for Google queries in chrome. If you are Tunneling only TCP it can be the case.